# How to create a condition inside the destroy method in controller in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I have this problem.
In my dashboard I want to Deactivate and Activate Account for my Registered Users and Admin

here's my controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   $getVal = Input::has('status');
    if($getVal === false) //if checkbox is set to false
    {
        $this->users->softDel($id);
    }
    else
    {
        //if checkbox is set to true
        $this->users->restoreDel($id);
    }
    return redirect('\users');
}
```

Model:

```
public function softDel($id)
{
     return User::where('id',$id)->delete();
}
public function restoreDel($id)
{
    return User::where('id',$id)->restore();
}
```

blade:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE' , 'route' => ['users.destroy',$data->id]]) !!}
    <!--checkbox-->
    {!! Form::checkbox('status',null,( $data->deleted_at != null ? false : true ),['data-toggle' => 'toggle', 'data-size' => 'small','data-on' => 'activate' , 'data-off' => 'deacticvate' , 'data-offstyle' => 'danger' , 'data-onstyle' => 'success', 'class' => 'status' , 'data-id' => ($data->id)]) !!}
    <!---->
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

here's my ajax request:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('.status').on('change',function(){
      var currentToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');//getting the token
      var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
          method: "DELETE",
          url: "/users/"+id,
          dataType: "json",
          data:  { _token: currentToken},
           success:function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }

       });
    });
});
```

I'm only using soft deletes to delete/restore any account..
My controller will only execute the IF statement.
I don't know what happened. Please help :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should pass `status` from your AJAX call on the basis of checkbox checked/unchecked like,

```
$.ajax({
    method: "DELETE",
    url: "/users/"+id,
    dataType: "json",
    data:  { _token: currentToken,status:this.checked?1:0},
    success:function(response) {
         console.log(response);
    }
});
```

And change your controller like,

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $getVal = Input::get('status'); //you will get 1 or 0 here
    if(!$getVal) { // if checkbox is unchecked, then status is 0
        $this->users->softDel($id);
    }
    else { // in case of 1
        //if checkbox is set to true
        $this->users->restoreDel($id);
    }
    return redirect('\users');
}
```

Comment: still not working sir.. both statement(if and else) are not working

Comment: Check in browser's console for your AJAX request?

Comment: Try to use `var_dump($getVal);exit;` for debug your code.